# Had the denizens known how wealthy their descendants would become ,many would have supposed those heirs lived amid peace

Tags: verbs

Q1： why does the sentence have two verbs?   one is "Had .....known "
another is" would have supposed "

Q2 :  what does  the ingredient of "Had the denizens  known"  mean?

Comment: What is the source of this sentence?? In English, one lives **in peace**, not amid peace.

Comment: The sentence has **a lot* more than two verbs. Why should it not have?

Answer (score 1):

The first verb *had ... known* is in a conditional clause.

It is precisely equivalent to *If the denizens had known ...*.

In  formal and literary English, a counter-factual "if" can be expressed by [inversion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_conditional_sentences#Inversion_in_condition_clauses) in this way.